# How can I run this code in an another file (using react native)?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I want to run this code inside another file (code). I'm new to react-native so I'm sorry if this is a stupid question.
This code calls a web service coded with php which provides data from a mysql database as json.

```
 import {Text, View} from 'react-native';
 import React, {Component} from 'react'; 

export default class App extends Component<Props> {
  
  state = { 
    data:[]
  }

  fetchData = async()=>{
    const response = await fetch('http://localhost/webservice.php');   //address of the database
    const users = await response.json();
    this.setState({data: users});
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchData();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
        data = {this.state.data}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
        renderItem = {({item}) =>

        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'yellow', padding: 10, margin: 8}}>
          <Text style={{color: '#000', fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{item.title}</Text>
          <Text style={{color: '#000'}}>{item.artist}, {item.releaseyear}</Text>

        </View> 
          }
        />
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

If I run just this code it works fine but I really don't know how to run it inside of other code. If I copy the code inside of the other code it gives me an error because there's "export" twice.

I would be very thankful if somebody can help me transform this code so I can run it inside of the other or (preferred) to run this code in the other code while it's an extra file.

Comment: You simply can import this component to another component and can use there .
Like :

 `import App from ''../../your path'';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a component that you have shared, which part of the code you want to add in the other component?

You need to make one more js file and you can use the same code there or  with amendments to make a new component and if you want to use the same component in some other component you just have to import it and use it like below.

```
import App from '../PathToAppComponent';

export default ParentComponet extends Component<Props> {
render() {
    return (
       <View>
        <App /> //you can add this component anywhere in your parent component.
        <View>
         //your parent component View
        </View>
       </View>
    )
}
```

Comment: I am glad, it helped.